# Subtracting a single column matrix from a 5x5 matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, subtraction

so say i have a column matrix A that is 5x1 and a 5x5 matrix B. i want to subract A from each column in B.

```
[b1,1 - a1   b1,2 - a1    b1,3 - a1     b1,4 - a1    b1,5 - a1]
[b2,1 - a2 ...................................................]
[b3,1 - a3 ............ 
[b4,1 - a4 ............
[b5,1 - a5 ..... etc
```

yes, that is a very terrible description, but i hope it gets the point across. I know that in octave it will automatically do this if you say B - A. But in matlab it wont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few options:

Just make `A` into a 5x5 matrix by repeating the columns:

```
B-repmat(A,1,size(B,2))
```

And the obligatory `bsxfun` method:

```
bsxfun(@minus,B,A)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say `bsxfun` is so much obligatory as it is better than `repmat`.  But of course, "better" is a relative term.

Comment: @TroyHaskin it sometimes seems that almost any Matlab question can be answered using `bsxfun`, so it almost feels obligatory sometimes!

Comment: Gotcha. Certainly when attempting to vectorize something, the answer is almost always `bsxfun`.

Comment: @David Agreed on the last comment!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a matrix that has 5 replicas of `a` as its columns and then subtract it from `B`:

```
C = B - repmat(a, 1, 5)
```